# Creating a paginated chronological query in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hopefully a relatively simple question here with using Firestore querys

I am trying to create essentially a news feed, sorting the newest content from the oldest content. That part is pretty easy, I use:

```
var first = db.collection("feeds/0/active").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(3);
```

Which retrieves the 3 newest entries in the news feed. My then idea is in the next query, to pull down the next 3 items in the feed. So if we are going by age, 4,5,6 in the collection in terms of how new the items are.

To do this I grab the last item in query one, and use that node's timestamp as my start at value in query 2:

```
  var first = db.collection("feeds/0/active").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(3);

      first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
      // Get the last visible document
      var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];


      var next = db.collection("feeds/0/active").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").startAt(lastVisible.data().timestamp).limit(3);
      next.get().then(function(docSn){
        console.log("SECOND QUERY!")
        docSn.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.data().message)
        })
      })
```

The Result of this code returns the same as the first query returns, the nodes 1, 2, 3 despite trying to tell the second query to start at node3

I also tried passing in a javascript object instead:

```
  var datevalue = Date.parse(lastVisible.data().timestamp)    
  var next = db.collection("feeds/0/active").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").startAt(datevalue).limit(3);
```

Which also unfortunately did not work.
I also tried passing in the entire snapshot item, and got the error
"Malforormed Calls from JS: field sizes are different.
[[9,38,38,38],[0,0,1,0],
etc.."

Not really clue where to start with this as I have read through the docs and any examples and I could find and can't seem to figure it out. The only other way I can think of implementing this is by using a Cloud Function to number each node upon creation.. but that feels hacky

Any help would be huge! Thanks

Comment: any idea anyone?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the exact same issue now.

Answer (score 4):

I have a collection called "books" with a field called "created" of type **Timestamp**. This is not a string. This is not a Date. Please see [the Timestamp docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). You need to specify in your settings that you want to use the new Timestamp type instead of Date for your timestamp fields. (See [docs for firestore settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings))

Example of initiating your firestore and set the TimestampsInSnapshots setting:

```
   var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: [APIKEY],
        authDomain: [FIREBASEAPPDOMAIN],
        projectId: [PROJECTID]
   });

   var firestore = firebase.firestore();
   var settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true }; // force Timestamp object instead of Date

   firestore.settings(settings);
```

When this is done, i've run the below code and I get the expected results. First query returns three results. Newest first, latest last.
The second query returns the next three items.

```
var first = db.collection('books').orderBy("created", "desc").limit(3);
console.log("FIRST QUERY!")
first.get().then(function(documentSnapshots) {    
    documentSnapshots.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.data().created.toMillis())
    });
    // Get the last visible document
    var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];

    var next = db.collection('books').orderBy("created", "desc")
         .startAfter(lastVisible.data().created).limit(3);
    next.get().then(function (docSn) {
        console.log("SECOND QUERY!")
        docSn.forEach(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc.data().created.toMillis())
        });
    });
});
```

The console from the above code:

```
FIRST QUERY!
1540573716371
1540573676652
1540573668643

SECOND QUERY!
1540573658893
1540573536420
1540536647891
```

Comment: how to get next three query?

Comment: @Ajay Malik, what did you try so far to get the next three?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks a lot for above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the entire list returned? Or, just the first node?

If you use `startAt`, then the first node in the second list will be the last node in the first list ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startAt)). I suggest using `startAfter` ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startAfter)).

Example:

```
    var db = firebase.firestore()
    var query = db.collection('feeds/0/active').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(3)
    query.get().then((firstSnapshot) => {
      var first3 = snapshot.docs
      query.startAfter(first3[2]).get().then((nextSnapshot) => {
        var next3 = snapshot.docs
      })
    })
```